# Android Image Problem and threshold

Tags: android, image, image-processing

Long time reader never posted until now.
Im having some trouble with Android, im implementing a library called JJIL its an open source imaging library.

My problem is this i need to run some analysis on an image and to do
so i need to have it in jjil.core.image format and once those
processes are complete i need to convert the changed image from
jjil.core.image to java.awt.image.
I cant seem to find a method of doing this does anyone have any ideas
or have any experience with this?

I would be grateful of any help.

Danny

Comment: java.awt.image is not available in the Android Dalvik VM. http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/packages.html

Comment: Damn it i didn't notice that thank you. 
Is there another way to get the RGB value of individual pixels in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let others know what you found...  probably you found that android.graphics.Bitmap has a getPixel(x,y) method that returns an int representing the ARGB value?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: Correct, that is exactly what I found.
I then compared every argb value to the one I wanted and seperated the background from the foreground.

I also used this algorithm

Math.cosh(Math.sqrt((((red-green)+(red - blue))/2)* (((red-green)*(red-green))/*squared*/ + ((red-blue)*(green-blue))) ))

Which I found in a book that will take rgb values and return them as a degree on the colour wheel.

Hope this is useful to someone else

Answer (score 0):

I have done some serious research into this and i have found that i can extract the rgb values of a bitmap image with a similar method. 
But the threshold that i was using the previous library for is now not possible because i have had to abandon the use of this library.

Is there a way to use colour matrix's to threshold the image? Or better still is there an inbuilt method that would do this automatically?

Thank you for any help.
Danny